# How do I do time.sleep in certain thread in python

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to make a constant updater that adds 2 of a resource each second. The problem is, when I do time.sleep(1), it puts the whole program to sleep and if I don't put it, the program crashes.

```
def coins(self):
    """ Creates the resource coins """
    self.coins = 0
    self.goldlabel = Label(self,text = str(self.coins) + " gold")
    self.goldlabel.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

def residences(self):
    self.residence = 0

def passivegold(self):
    amount = self.residence
    if self.residence > 0:
        add = amount * 2
        self.coins += add
        # time.sleep(1)
        self.goldlabel.configure(text = str(self.coins) + " gold")
```

Comment: Time.sleep affects the thread in which it is called.

Comment: There don't seem to be any threads in the code you've shown us. Do you create threads somewhere? (If you think that some GUI library is creating threads, you'll probably want to read about [event loops](https://www.google.com/search?q=event+loops), which are often confused with threading.)

Comment: If your entire program is stopping, that means you only have one thread (the main thread). If you have multiple, threads, then this won't happen.

Comment: I don't see any thread there. Where's the thread?

Comment: For that matter, there doesn't seem to be any *code* in the code you've shown us.  When do these functions (methods? where's the class?) get called?

Comment: So how do I make more threads are define more threads in the program.